# Training by which algorithm has the most accuracy for face recognition in python using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I have used OpenCV face recognition using python, by using haarcascade classifiers it does not have enough accuracy for recognition. what is your recommendations to improve the accuracy? can using another algorithm help for better accuracy?

Comment: Which method did u use?

Comment: haarcascade classifiers and trained by LBPHRecognizer method

Comment: haar cascade is good. but it has its own limitation, if you have enough data and computation capacity it is better to try Deep learning  Models like CNN using tensorflow or keras for much better accuracy. Read this [post](https://www.quora.com/Which-one-is-better-for-face-recognition-OpenCV-or-TensorFlow) might give more understanding.